# Wirtinger calculus on general holomorphic vector bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

For any holomorphic vector bundle $\mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow E \rightarrow M$ on a complex manifold, one can define a Dolbeault operator $\overline{\partial}_E$ which obeys the Leibniz rule and has the property $\overline{\partial}_E\circ\overline{\partial}_E = 0$. Given a local frame $(z^1,\dots,z^n)$ with $z^j = x^j + \mathrm{i}y^j$, is this enough to define a Wirtinger calculus which behaves as if $E$ were the tangent bundle? Namely, for a function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ can $\overline{\partial}_E f$ be then locally expressed as $\sum_j \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} + \mathrm{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^j}\right)\mathrm{d}\overline{z}^j$, and is there an analogous operator $\partial_E$ such that $\partial_E +\overline{\partial}_E$ is the complex deRham differential?

Comment: If you equip $E$ with a hermitian metric, then there is a unique connection $\nabla$ which is compatible with the metric and for which $\nabla^{0,1} = \bar{\partial}_E$. This is called the *Chern connection* and can be written as $\nabla = \nabla^{1,0} + \nabla^{0,1} = \partial_E + \bar{\partial}_E$. Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you! But do we know anything about the operator $\partial_E$, for instance, an expression explicit or in terms of the Dolbeault operator of the underlying manifold? Are $\partial_E$ and $\overline{\partial}_E$ dependent on the hermitian metric?

Comment: The operator $\partial_E$ depends on the hermitian metric, but $\bar{\partial}_E$ doesn't.

Comment: Also, the operator $\bar{\partial}_E$ acts on sections of $E$, so $\bar{\partial}_Ef$ is not defined.